# Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm using DynamoDB and for query API for all ComparisonOperators except "EQ" it keeps giving me "Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation" error.

What is the reason?

```
{"TableName":"My_Table_name",
    "IndexName":"titleIndex",
    "Select":"ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
    "KeyConditions":
        {"title":
            {"AttributeValueList":[{"S":"title2"}],
            "ComparisonOperator":"NE"}
        }
}
```

Comment: There is an answer that could be really helpful here -
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966080/dynamodb-query-with-comparison-operators

Answer (score 7):

For query operation, only the following comparison operators are supported:

`EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN`

You can use `NE` for scan operation.

Refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

Answer (score 1):

That may be helpful:
[DynamoDB query with Comparison Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966080/dynamodb-query-with-comparison-operators)

you can get the  additional info from this :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html
For KeyConditions, only the following comparison operators are supported:

EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN