# Python Boto3 DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to query records from DynamoDB table using "IN" comparison operator, below is my code:

```
import boto3

# Create a DynamoDB client
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

# Define the query parameters
table_name = 'tb'

# Perform the query
response = dynamodb.query(
    TableName=table_name,
    Select='SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
    AttributesToGet=[
        'col1',
        'col2',
        'col3',
        'col4'
    ],
    KeyConditions={
        'col1': {
            'AttributeValueList': [
                {
                    'S':'abc'                    
                },
                {
                    'S':'def'                    
                }
            ],
            'ComparisonOperator': 'IN'
        }
    }
)
print(response)
```

I am trying to query all records where 'col1' is 'abc' or 'def', but I got the error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation
```

Answer (score 1):

For query, only the following operations are supported as KeyConditions:

EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN

Reference: [Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293175/attempted-conditional-constraint-is-not-an-indexable-operation)

For your use case, you might want to use multiple queries, or use "scan" (more expensive) instead of "query". Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036422/21878238) for the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such API as BatchQuery and the `IN` operator is not supported for a [`KeyConditionExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html).

However, if you would like a workaround you can use PartiQL [`ExecuteStatement`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/execute_statement.html):

`SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM tb WHERE col1 IN ['ABC', 'DEF']`

This will allow you to execute a Query on up to 50 keys.