# Filter expression to check empty value is present in array or not in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have data stored as [ { "S" : "" } ] in DynamoDB. I want to check whether the record contain empty value or not so I tried

```
FilterExpression : `contains (columnName, :data)`
   ExpressionAttributeValues:{
   ":data": ""
}
```

But i am getting no result from query. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make search using "contains" with DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793888/how-to-make-search-using-contains-with-dynamodb)

Comment: @malarres no since there are other columns too which is having data in it and tried the contains with it it is working but when it comes to [ { "S" : "" } ] this kind of data its ot filtering

Answer (score 0):

I've created 2 items in the DDB table. 1 with empty value, 1 with non-empty value as follows:

[image]

Then I ran this query:

```js
{
  "TableName": "xxx",
  "FilterExpression": "#DDB_data5vizmh5osmv = :data5vizmh5osmv",
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#DDB_data5vizmh5osmv": "data"
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":data5vizmh5osmv": ""
  }
}
```

And here are the results I got. I filtered 1 item with empty value.

[image]